# Multiprocessing in Spyder 5.4.3

Tags: python, multiprocessing, spyder

I just want to check if I am doing something wrong. It looks like Spyder IDE does not work with Python multiprocessing library. Here is my code:

In the same folder I have two functions:

**square_function.py:**

```
def square_function(x):
    return x*x
```

**main.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import square_function

with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(square_function.square_function, [1, 2, 3]))
```

When I open and execute `main.py` in Spyder (interactively), it simply hangs and does not generate anything. The same code runs fine in Jupyter Notebook. Am I using multiprocessing correctly? Is this a bug in Spyder.

Comment: Do you need to enclose the `with Pool(...` block within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block? As an aside, you are creating a pool of 5 processes to execute 3 submitted tasks. That seems to me wasteful.